# C# Enter Timestamp at Enter in Richtexbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timestamp, return, richtextbox

I am trying to add a timestamp into a richtextbox everytime i hit "enter" on keyboard. The code below partially works, however at Enter a new line is added below my Timestamp. I then have to Backspace to type next to my timestamp.

Any suggestions please send.

```
private void richTextBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode ==  Keys.Return)
    {
        richTextBox2.SelectedText = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " --";                
    }                  
}
```

Comment: What's your problem so far?

Comment: That new line must be the "enter" you just pressed. It doesn't ignore the fact that you wanted a new line by pressing enter, it just adds it after the timestamp. You can try to override the e.KeyCode with an empty string to prevent it from being added or changed the e.Handled state which is something like jQuery's "PreventDefault" method.

Comment: what are you using WPF,winforms ??

Comment: @Nick: I think `e.Handled = true;` will give the desired output.

Comment: It works... but on enter it just keeps adding timestamp to same line and does create new line.

Comment: Genius! Thats exactly what im trying to do. Ill explore that idea. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code as follows:

```
private void richTextBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        richTextBox2.SelectedText = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " --";
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

When you hit enter, a new line is inserted. So e.Handled will not let this happen.

Comment: Hi, I do want new line but with timestamp and enter text next to timestamp. LIke 03:49am -- (enter text here). Rather than select backspace to enter desired text.